# How i can develop windows phone 8.0 app in visual studio 2013 Comunity?

Tags: visual-studio, windows-phone-8, windows-phone, windows-phone-8.1

I have windows 8.1 OS. and when I choose Windows Phone App in VS it create Windows Phone 8.1 App without choice

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the Windows Phone templates in Visual Studio, you'll find two types of templates: `Windows Phone` and `Windows Phone Silverlight` (see the image below).

[image]

The `Windows Phone` templates refer to the XAML OS platform, which is only available for Windows Phone 8.1.
The `Windows Phone Silverlight` templates refer to the Silverlight OS platform, which is available for both 8.0 and 8.1. So if you want to create Windows Phone 8.0 app, you'll need to use one of these templates.

Answer (score 1):

You need to install SDK. I would highly suggest to develop new apps as 8.1 XAML (not silverlight) apps for future portability.

You can download SDK's here: https://dev.windows.com/en-us/develop/download-phone-sdk

Comment: Im want to create new apps as 8.1 XAML, but I need use sql server compact toolbox for creating datacontext. and this tool don't support 8.1

Comment: I went for 8.1 but unfortunately had to backport it to 8.0 as Microsoft removed background location tracking between 8.0 and 8.1... [User Voice 1](https://wpdev.uservoice.com/forums/110705-dev-platform/suggestions/6102994-background-location-tracking-in-windows-phone-8-1) [User Voice 2](https://wpdev.uservoice.com/forums/253374-missing-platform-apis/suggestions/6088960-continuous-background-location-tracking-like-wp8)